# Find the probability of drawing 3 aces at random from a deck of 52 ordinary cards if the cards are not replaced.

Tags: probability

Ex: **Find the probability of drawing 3 aces at random from a deck of 52 ordinary cards if the cards are not replaced.**

Here's what I did:

> The probability of choosing the first ace = $\dfrac{^4C_1}{^{52}C_1}$
>
> The probability of choosing the second ace = $\dfrac{^3C_1}{^{51}C_1}$
>
> The probability of choosing the third ace = $\dfrac{^2C_1}{^{50}C_1}$
>
> The probability is = $\dfrac{^4C_1}{^{52}C_1}\times\dfrac{^3C_1}{^{51}C_1}\times\dfrac{^2C_1}{^{50}C_1}=\dfrac{1}{5525}$

But the answer is given as $\dfrac{1}{17,576}$

> Please tell me where did I go wrong?

Comment: What are all of the $C_1$ for?

Comment: What is the full wording of the question.  Are you drawing three and only three cards?  Are you perhaps drawing a full hand of five cards?  @Sean, presumably it is notation for combinations, i.e. $4C_1 = \binom{4}{1}$.  It is quite redundant to write that way though, since anything choose 1 is itself.

Comment: That was my thought, @JMoravitz. Needs some format tweaking one way or another. Also, the context might make a difference here. Hadn't thought of that.

Comment: All interpretations I can think of don't seem to have the listed probability of $\frac{1}{17576}$.  If the problem's full wording is: "draw three cards from a standard 52 card playing deck without replacement: what is the probability all three are aces?" then the answer is as you say $\frac{4}{\binom{52}{3}}=\frac{1}{5525}$.  Unless there is missing information about the question, it would appear you have the correct answer and the answer key is off.  Perhaps it might have that answer in a conditional probability scenario...

Comment: $17576 = 26^3$.  That's not definitive, but it sure strongly suggests some kind of card-drawing problem *with* replacement.

Answer (score 2):

As a number of prople have already pointed out, your answer is correct.

However, if you are using combinations, it would be good to write it as ${4\choose 3}$/${52\choose 3}$

You could also directly work it out as $\frac {4\cdot 3\cdot 2} {52\cdot 51\cdot 50}$

Comment: ${4\choose 3}$ is not 4*3*2*1. It is ${4!/(3!(4-3))!}$ .

Likewise, ${52\choose 3}$ is not 52*51*50. It is ${52!/(3!(52-3)!)}$

Comment: @arboreal84:What is your point ? Since *probability* has been asked for, I have shown that it can be solved in two ways, one using combinations, and another using permutations.